# Can push docker images to Artifactory, but can't pull

Tags: docker, artifactory, devops

Having a strange issue at the moment trying to pull down my docker images from Artifactory, any takes would be appreciated.

When I run 'docker pull' I get the following:

```
[mark@host]$ sudo /usr/bin/docker pull ficc-artifactory.bns/product/docker-image:0.2.0
Error response from daemon: unknown: Not Found
```

This made me think that fine, perhaps I need to login to the registry first (so that the daemon knows about it), but no dice:

```
[mark@host]$ sudo /usr/bin/docker login -u "mark" -p "pwd" -e "mark@email.com" ficc-artifactory.bns
Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code [404] : {
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Not Found"
  } ]
}
```

Note that the certificate is in place:

```
[mark@host]$ sudo ls -ltr /etc/docker/certs.d/ficc-artifactory.bns/ca.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1064 Jan 14 00:15 /etc/docker/certs.d/ficc-artifactory.bns/ca.crt
```

**Important to note that I can 'docker push' to the repository without any issues.**

Furthermore, I've confirmed that the 'mark' user has all available permissions to the Artifactory repository acting as the Docker registry.

I'm sure this is fairly trivial, but any insight would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did this happen recently or did it never work? Anything in the Artifactory logs when this happens? What type of reverse proxy are you using (post the relevant config as well please)?  what version of Artifactory are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on RHEL 7 with docker 1.12.x. What i did to fix the problem is add the following option to the docker daemon on startup `OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false'`

The important part is the `--signature-verification=false` after adding this to the docker daemon my artifactory connection works!

You can add it to `/etc/sysconfig/docker` or the `docker.service` file at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` if you use systemd or systemctl.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this solution did not work here (RHEL7, Docker Version: 1.13.1, API version: 1.26)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an old thread, but I will chime in anyway.

The `docker login` is not the issue. If it were, your error message would be something like: `Error response from daemon: Get https://artifactory.company.com/v2/docker_image/manifests/latest: unknown: Authentication is required`

This appears to be an issue with your reverse proxy not being able to forward your request correctly.

Like at @fundeldman asked: Can you post the configuration of your reverse-proxy?